# Changing Site Name in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-cms

I am currently following a tutorial which introduces a custom Bootstrap 3 template and builds a Django site using it. In the tutorial they suggest that one changes the following template snippet:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Start Bootstrap</a>
```

to the following snippet.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">{{ request.site.name }}</a>
```

However, when I make this change, no site name shows. I am wondering where I should be setting this name. If it helps, I am using Django CMS and there is only one site called `example.com`populated in the `Sites` section of the Administration.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, found [this in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/sites/#site-middleware).

> If you often use this pattern:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>
> def my_view(request):
>     site = Site.objects.get_current()
> ```
>
> ... there is simple way to avoid repetitions. Add **django.contrib.sites.middleware.CurrentSiteMiddleware** to **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES**. The middleware sets the site attribute on every request object, so you can use request.site to get the current site.

Answer (score 2):

You can add site name or change existing site called `example.com`  in the `Sites` section of the Administration.

To access `Site` object you need to provide `SITE_ID` in your `settings.py`

If you are changing `example.com` then use SITE_ID = 1 in settings

To render site name in django templates, get value from site model using

```
 from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
 current_domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
```

then pass `current_domain` to template

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to enable the sites framework, refer to [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/sites/#s-enabling-the-sites-framework).

Answer (score 0):

first yo have to understand that in the setting you have a site_id set to 1 and in database migrations an example site with domain name example.com is created. So, you have two options:

1. You can change this default from django site models like this: `python manage.py shell -c "from django.contrib.sites.models import Site; Site.objects.filter(domain='example.com').update(name='My Site', domain='mysite.tld')"` then you restart the server.
2. You can insert a new row in the site models like this: `python manage.py shell -c "from django.contrib.sites.models import Site; mysite,_=Site.objects.get_or_create(id=101, name='mysite.tld', domain='mysite.tld'); print(mysite.id, mysite.name)"` Then change the site_id in the settings to the new site_id which should be 2 since it is the second new row.

You can take a look at this [Github trend](https://github.com/maxking/docker-mailman/issues/12) for more clearity.